# Chat en PHP y AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy tratando de realizar un chat general en una pagina para que varios usuarios interactuen, un estilo "foro", pero me ha surgido un problema y no logro determinar cual es...

Lo estoy programando con AJAX y PHP. Estoy utilizando el 000webhost para corroborar si lo que he programado está bien y lo puedo subir a mi página pero justamente acá está el problema.

Cuando utilizo webhost al intentar insertar los valores dentro de mi base de datos doy enter se envian y el cuadro de chat vuelve a vaciarse lo cual ocurre correctamente, se guarda y se muestra el mensaje en el foro. Pero luego, cuando hago lo mismo en mi pagina web (teniendo exactamente el mismo nombre en todo lo correspondiente a la base de datos) solo se "envia", el cuadro de chat se vacía pero no se inserta en la bdd.

Dejo el código para que lo vean, en la base de datos simplemente tengo un id_chat(INT AI), user(INT), message(VARCHAR) y date(TIMESTAMP).

Por alguna razón en el servidor de mi página no lo pueda ejecutar y en webhost o en el localhost mismo si?

ARCHIVO CHAT.PHP

```
    <div class="cuadroChat">
    <div class="chatbox">
    <h3>Escribe tu mensaje</h3>
        <form action="" method="GET">
            <textarea class="txtarea" id="message" name="message" maxlength="250"></textarea>
        </form>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>**Presiona enter para enviar**</p>
    </div>
  <div class="chathistory"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            loadChat();
        });

        $('#message').keyup(function(e){
            var message = $(this).val();
            if( e.which == 13 ){
                $.get('ajax.php?action=SendMessage&message='+message, function(response){

                    loadChat();
          $('#message').val('');
                });
            }
        });
        function loadChat()
        {
            $.get('ajax.php?action=getChat', function(response){

                $('.chathistory').html(response);
            });
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            loadChat();
        }, 2000);
    </script>
```

ARCHIVO AJAX.PHP

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require '../database.php';
if( isset($_REQUEST['action']) ){
    switch( $_REQUEST['action'] ){
        case "SendMessage":
            session_start();
            if (!empty($_REQUEST['message'])){
            $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO chat set user=?, message=?");
            $query->execute([$_SESSION['user_id'], $_REQUEST['message']]);
            echo 1;}
        break;
        case "getChat":
            $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from chat inner join users on chat.user=users.id order by chat.id_chat desc limit 80");
            $query->execute();
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    ?>
    <?php
            $chat = '';
            foreach( $rs as $r ){
                $chat .=  '<div class="siglemessage"><img src="../css/imagenes/escudos/'.$r->equipo.'.png" width="15" height="15"><strong>'.$r->username.':  </strong>'.$r->message.'</div>';
            }
            echo $chat;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: le as dado al inspector con `f12` o viendo directamente que sale en `ajax.php` al enviar un parametro por get?

Comment: Me sale el mensaje enviado pero curiosamente no se guarda en la bdd, como si faltase algún parámetro pero no sé la verdad

Comment: y directamente en el `ajax.php`?